# How to get min and max value from the same column at same time from database in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get the minimum and maximum values, at the same time, with one query in CodeIgniter.

Here is my code snippet:

```
$this->db->select_min('table.col1');
$this->db->select_max('table.col1');
$this->db->select('table.col2');
$this->db->from('atm_rates');
$this->db->order_by('table.col2');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: write query like SELECT MIN(PRICE) AS MinPrice, MAX(PRICE) AS MaxPrice FROM PRODUCTS

Answer (score 1):

You can try this select:

`$this->db->select('MAX(col1), MIN(col1)');
$query = $this->db->get('table');`

OR

`$sql = "SELECT MAX(col1) AS max, MIN(col1) as min FROM table;
$query = $this->db->query($sql)->get();`

And then

`return $query->result_array();`